# Casting NULL to a struct pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct

Is there any benefit of casting NULL to a struct pointer in C ?

For example:

```
typedef struct List
{
....
} List;

List *listPtr = ((List *) NULL) ;
```

Example from PostgreSQL source:

```
#define NIL                     ((List *) NULL)
```

http://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__list_8h_source.html

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. You can assign NULL to any pointer without any cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In assignment example the explicit cast make no useful sense. However, it seems that you the question is really about `#define NIL ((List *) NULL)` macro, whose usability extends beyond assignment.

One place where it might make sense is when you pass it to a variadic function or to a function declared without a prototype. The standard `NULL` can be defined as`0` or `0L` or `((void *) 0)` or in some other way, meaning that it might be interpreted differently in such type-less contexts. An explicit cast will make sure that it is interpreted correctly as a pointer.

For example, this is generally invalid (behavior is undefined)

```
void foo();

int main() {
  foo(NULL);
}

void foo(List *p) {
  /* whatever */
}
```

while replacing the call with

```
foo(NIL);
```

makes it valid.

Answer (score 6):

No null is null, it's as null as you can get, you might think zero is pretty null but that's just peanuts compared to null.

Comment: Still some HHGTTG fans in this new generation then ;-)

Comment: oh, no, unfortunately not. `sizeof(NULL)` can vary from `1` to `8` depending on how `NULL` is defined.

Comment: @JensGustedt that's just the representation of NULL in our universe.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any benefit of casting NULL to a struct pointer in C

There's none. It should be simply:

```
List *listPtr = NULL;
```

Moreover, if the object has static storage (say, like a global variable) you don't even need to initialize it to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is benefit.
In this example, you can use `size_of_attribute()` macro to determine a size in bytes of a specific struct attribute, **without actually creating an instance of said struct**.

```
#define size_of_attribute(Struct, Attribute) sizeof(((Struct*)NULL)->Attribute)
```